# My index file is only showing one database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, erb

I'm trying to list all "pits" which are bascially the same thing as "posts" in my app. However, my pits/index is only showing the first pit created versus listing all of them. I can't see any errors in my view or controller. I have a feeling its something small and may need another pair of eyes to point it out for me. Thanks.

index.html.erb

```
<div class = "container list-pits"> 
  <% @pit.each do |pit| %>

 <div class = "row">

   <div class = "container">
    <div class = "well pit-well"> 
       <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>
          <br>
            <p><%= pit.summary %></p>
            <p>Replies (<%= pit.comments.count %>)</p>
          <br>
            <p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, current_user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>
            <%= link_to "Join Pit", '#', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

pits_controller

```
class PitsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @pit = Pit.new
end

def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pit = @user.pits
  @pits = Pit.order('created_at DESC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
    if @pit.save
      redirect_to @pit
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def show
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
end

private

def pit_params
    params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
end

end
```

Comment: I guess your `@user` has only 1 `pit`.

Comment: Yes, however, I'm trying to list all pits for all users here. It was working a few days ago and then I added comments, reset my database, and its only showing the one pit. I did create new user without a pit and it still showed the one pit by the other user when I went to my index file. - Correction, I also created another pit by a different user and it still showed only the first created pit by the other different user.

Comment: In your action, you are finding single user and then finding all pits for it

Comment: I see. Should I add something like @user = User.all. or something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pit = @user.pits
  @pits = Pit.order('created_at DESC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end
```

Firstly, you dont need `@pit = Pit.all`, because you are overwriting `@pit` with `@pit = @user.pits`.
My guess is `@user` with chosen id (`@user = User.find(params[:id])`) has only 1 object of Pit type.

If you want to show all pits, then remove `@pit = @user.pits` and keep `@pit = Pit.all`

PS: In your create action there is `current_user.pits.create(pit_params)` and just after that you are trying to `@pit.save`. You should change the first one to `current_user.pits.new(pit_params)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So remove the @pit.save? Because I'm currently getting undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass when implementing current_user.pits.new(pits_params)

Comment: You should keep `@pit =` so the whole line is `@pit = current_user.pits.new(pit_params)` :)